# POM import failed: io.thorntail:bom-all:pom:2.7.0.Final

Tags: java, maven, ejb

I'm following an e-book and I can't go ahead because of the error there in the pom.xml file.

I have this following errors:
Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: io.thorntail:bom-all:pom:2.7.0.Final failed to transfer from http://repo.mj.gov.br/repository/maven-group/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact io.thorntail:bom-all:pom:2.7.0.Final from/to nexus (http://repo.mj.gov.br/repository/maven-group/): transfer failed for http://repo.mj.gov.br/repository/maven-group/io/thorntail/bom-all/2.7.0.Final/bom-all-2.7.0.Final.pomJava(0)

```
<dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

      <dependency>

        <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>

        <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>

        <version>${version.thorntail}</version>

        <scope>import</scope>

        <type>pom</type>

      </dependency>

    </dependencies>

  </dependencyManagement>
```

And this error:
Project build error: ‘dependencies.dependency.version’ for io.thorntail:jaxrs:jar is missing.Java(0)

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

How do I resolve this? I'm using VsCode Java.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was without access to the repository. Problem solved.
http://repo.mj.gov.br/repository/maven-group/